# $\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \lim_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = L$; $P(x) Q(x)$ - polynomials with degree $P(x) \leq $ degree $Q(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital

This is a true statement, right? And $L = 0$. I could prove this using algebraic limit theorems and taking $P(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + ... + a_0$ and $Q(x) = b_m x^m + b_{m-1} x^{m-1} + ... + b_0$.

$\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \dfrac{a_n x^{n-m} + a_{n-1} x^{n-m-1} + \dots + a_0 x^{-m} } {b_m + b_{m-1} x^{-1} + \dots + b_0 x^{-m}}$

Here, everything goes to $0$ at the numerator thus $L = 0$.

Is this valid argument?

Comment: That only works for $m>n$. For $m=n$ you don't quite get $L=0$ (in general).

Comment: No, the statement is not correct: If for arbitrary fns P,Q you have lim P/Q = L, that does not imply that P and Q are polynomials. I'm going to assume you mean "Let P,Q be polynomials of degree $n \le m$ - Then, lim P/Q = L, and L=0 if and only if n=m. Then yes, your statement is true. But as written, your statement is false.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven forget about the $0$. But both limits are equal and exist right? when $x$ tends to $+-\infty$

Comment: @WillSherwood Your assumption is what I meant.  Forget about $0$. In either case limit exists and both limits are equal. Am I correct?

Comment: In either case? You mean no matter the order of the degrees of the polynomials? Then, again, no, because the limit can diverge to $+\infty$, i.e. simply $x/1$.

Comment: Otherwise I don't know which case you're referring to, maybe whether or not L=0? Then yes, that is why I wrote lim P/Q = L, because the limit will be the same going in either the $+$ or $-\infty$ direction. :)

Comment: @WillSherwood I mean the degree of numerator $\leq$ the degree of the denominator, the given condition satisfy